# Most efficient way to append multiple data to FormData in jquery

Tags: jquery, form-data

Just looking to see what the most efficient way to add data to FormData. The 2 ways I can think of is like:

```
var file = document.getElementById("fileName").files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
formData.append("id", $("#ID").val());
formData.append("Name", $("#nameOne").val());
formData.append("Name2", $("#nameTwo").val());
formData.append("Name3", $("#nameThree").val());
```

or:

```
var file = document.getElementById("fileName").files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append({ "file": file, 
                  "id": $("#ID").val()), 
                  "Name": $("#nameOne").val(), 
                  "Name2": $("#nameTwo").val(), 
                  "Name3": $("#nameThree").val()
               });
```

So is it either one of these or is there an even more efficient way to append files/data together?

Comment: Well... You second case is invalid and will throw, and the first one is the only valid. So... if "*efficient*" must includes "*That actually works*" then go for the first one.

Comment: Most efficient is to pass whole form to `FormData()` making sure control element names match names shown

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is to pass form element to `FormData()` and make sure `name` on controls match what you want to send

```
<form id="myForm">
    File: <input name="file" type="file"/>
    ID: <input name="id" />
    Name: <input name="Name" />
    Name 2: <input name="Name2" />
</form>
```

---

```
var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#myForm'));
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the **important** note about `name`. (And btw, the simplest is to submit() this form ;-) )

Comment: @Kaiido last statment true...but likely wanting to send via ajax is my assumption

Comment: Could also want to append some data that are not in the same form, or even not in a form at all.